Rails globalize error undefined method `translates' for Post:Class
I am using rails 6.1.4 and added transalations table to post via this migration
class TransalatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    def self.up
      Post.create_translation_table!({
        :title => :string,
        :body => :text
      }, {
        :migrate_data => true,
        :remove_source_columns => true
      })
    end
  
    def self.down
      Post.drop_translation_table! :migrate_data => true
    end
  end
end


My post model looks like this
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    translates :title,:body

    validates :title, presence:true
    validates :body, presence:true
end


What is exactly happening wrong ? I am exactly following the steps any help will be appreciated

Did you add globalize to Gemfile and bundle it?

I added it to the gemfile . It still didn't identify transalates method
